# One service reference/client for web service C# .NET

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, soap, wsdl

I have a question regarding web service references in VS.

The problem is quite simple I have one URL (say www.something-some.example.com) which hosts lots of web services and I will have to consume most of them. So is there any way I can create one service reference and only add dynamically WSDL

(for example - 
 www.something-some.example.com/xxxx.do?WSDL, 
 www.something-some.example.com/yyyyyyy.do?WSDL, etc.
)

So I don't have to create x references which is quite messy and confusing.

What I am looking for is something like this in php:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($this->server."/".$wsdl, $this->soapParams);
```

I have all the wsdl for this purpose.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the Service Contract Interface? Or can you create them?

Comment: It's not WCF service and it's 3rd party software so I can't add anything there. I have all the WSDL, Methods names and URLs. I just don't want to create x references as one web service represents one table in that system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time a found a way how to do that, in my case it was not usable, because we get access to REST, but if somebody need to do it [here](http://where-madness-lies.co.uk/computers/programming/dynamically-calling-a-web-service-without-a-web-reference-in-c/)